# How to add Video file and TextView in one UIVIEWCONTROLLER?

Tags: ipad, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to add Video file in my iPad application.

I have use MPMoviePlayerController for this it work fine.

but i have one problem this controller is covering hole WINDOW of iPad.

I want my UIViewController should contain  one textView, Navigation Bar, one Running Video file,

and four UIButton. Have can i achive this?

Comment: This can easily done by using [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by add that MPMoviePlayer as subView of your view, means addSubview on your view with fix frame.

like this,

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds]; // myView is your parent view which hold your player 
[myView addSubview: player.view];

[player play];
```

For more references **check [this.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

Comment: Hey I am  using MPMoviePlayerController right now. But it show video in my full UIViewContriller. Can i make it small and use other part for TextView and other UIButton.. if Yes then how?